# send form with Symfony crawler without save button (autosave function)

Tags: php, symfony, testing, web-crawler, autosave

I'm writting functional test for symfony and I have problem with sending form on page, where is no any save button, only autosave function.

*Usually I first located save button, fill form with data and than save*

```
    // find the add button
    $saveButton = $crawler->filter('button.btn-save');

    // fill the form with data and submit
    $form = $saveButton->form();

    // submit empty form
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can call form() method on the form element itself.

```
$form = $crawler->filter('css-selector-to-form')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```